# Weyl group actions on standard parabolic subgroups of classical groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of local fields and $G=U(V)$ a unitary group associated to hermitian space $V$ over $E/F$. We fix a minimal parabolic subgroup $P_0$ of $G$ and call $P=NM$ a standard parabolic subgroup of $G$ if it contains $P_0$. Write $M=\GL_{a_1}(E) \times \dotsb \times \GL_{a_r}(E) \times \U(W)$, where $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Let $A_0$ be the maximal split torus of $G$ and $N_G(A_0)$ and $Z_G(A_0)$ its normalizer and centralizer respectively. If $P'=N'M'$ is another standard parabolic subgroup (i.e., there is a Weyl group element $w \in N_G(A_0)(F) / Z_G(A_0)(F)$ such that $w \cdot P=P'$), then I am wondering whether $M'$ should be of the form $\GL_{b_1}(E) \times \dotsb \times \GL_{b_r}(E) \times \U(W)$ and $\{b_1,\dotsc,b_r\}$ is a permutation of $\{a_1,\dotsc,a_r\}$?

And if $\rho=\rho_1 \boxtimes \dotsb \boxtimes \rho_r \boxtimes \tau$ is a representation of $M$, then $w\cdot \rho$ is also the form of $\rho_{S(1)} \boxtimes \dotsb \boxtimes \rho_{S(r)} \boxtimes \tau$, where $S$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,\dotsc,r\}$?

Comment: Dear Monty, I suggest that you edit your question. Make an effort to explain your notation (and maybe to correct grammar and  typos ... ). What is "another associated standard parabolic subgroup"? Associated to what? What are standard parabolic subgroups if you have not chosen a maximal torus and a Borel subgroup? Where does your element $w$ live? In $F$-points or in $\bar F$-points? The answer to your question might depend on all this.

Comment: @Mikhail, Oh, I have read your comment so late. I am very sorry for not explaing the  notations in detail. I corrected my question more precisely. I would appreciate if you see it again.

Comment: The question is still not clear. First, $w\cdot P$ is not standard. Second, you write: "then I am wondering whether $M'$ should be of the form ${\rm GL}_{b_1}(E) \times \dotsb \times {\rm GL}_{b_r}(E) \times U(W)$..."  What do you mean by "of the form"?

Comment: Anyway, if you state your question clearly and read the description of the Weyl group on page 1272 of the reference in the answer of "Not a grad student", you can answer your question yourself, at least in the case when $G$ is quasi- split. Concerning the general case, you can ask a question at Math.StackExchange.com for the description of the Weyl group and the root system of your group $G$.

Comment: @Mikhail, thank you! The all I wanted for is on the reference of Goldberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, since the Weyl group of the quasi-split unitary group is not the symmetric group. See page 1272 of Goldberg, "R-Groups and Elliptic Representations of Unitary Groups," http://www.jointmathematicsmeetings.org/proc/1995-123-04/S0002-9939-1995-1224616-6/S0002-9939-1995-1224616-6.pdf

Comment: The reference in the answer has no page 1272.

Comment: Thanks. There are several papers by David Goldberg with similar titles.

Comment: This seems to answer the converse of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much! The reference you informed me is the very one I am searching for. There is another action like taking contragredient representation. But I am still wondering why for $GL(n)$, there is no such involution action but only permutation. Do you know some intuitive reason for why there does not Weyl group element corresponding to taking $g^{-1}$ to each components of $GL(n_i)$?

Comment: @May I ask you one more? Is there a similar involution Weyl group action for other classical group like symplectic group?